# selenium ide is written in which language?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have to write a recorder and playback feature for browser based applications. I am first exploring the open source alternatives available. I am fluent with java. I am wondering in which language selenium ide written in?. My research shows javascript, but still would like to confirm it with someone who is familiar with this domain.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know in which language Selenium is written (C++ ?) but your question is about the programming language to develop in Selenium. Appears it is JavaScript. You may read this: https://www.guru99.com/introduction-selenuim-ide.html

Comment: @claude31 in selenium ide, one can just record and play clicks on browser based application. I have write a record and playback tool just like selenium ide, and thus searching in which language is selenium written, if I have to use its code. The only programming language I am comfortable with it java and C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be javascript.

It's an open source project so you can see the code here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide